I have no error in my web application but my Smtp server doesn't send any email
Here is my error:

IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.

And here is my code:
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    public async Task SendEmailAsync(EmailModel email)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage()
        {
            From = new MailAddress("Myusername@gmail.com", "username"),
            To = { email.To },
            Subject = email.Subject,
            Body = email.Body,
            IsBodyHtml = true,
        };

        SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",25) // Host => for example: webmail.codeyad.com
            {
                Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", ""), // UserName == Email
                EnableSsl = true
            };
        smtpServer.Send(mail);
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

MMenta.Tools.EmailSender.SendEmailAsync(EmailModel email) in EmailSender.cs
smtpServer.Send(mail);

MMenta.Controllers.AccountController.Register(RegisterVM model) in AccountController.cs
await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(new EmailModel(user.Email, "تایید حساب", body));`


[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.IsSent = false;
        return View();
    }

    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationUser()
    {
        UserName = model.UserName,
        Email = model.Email,
        PhoneNumber = model.Phone,
        NickName = model.UserName,
        user_avatar = model.user_avatar,
    }, model.Password); 

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        foreach (var err in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, err.Description);
           ViewBag.IsSent = false;
           return View();
        }
    }

    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
   // var mobileCode = await _userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, "Phone");

   // return RedirectToAction("ConfirmMobile", new { phone = user.PhoneNumber, token = });
   //
   var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
    token = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token));
    string? callBackUrl = Url.ActionLink("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, token = token },
        Request.Scheme);
    string body = await _viewRenderService.RenderToStringAsync("_RegisterEmail", callBackUrl);
    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(new EmailModel(user.Email, "تایید حساب", body));
    ViewBag.IsSent = true;
    return View();
}


try:
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
in a command window, to see if the problem is outside of your code first. Its a good starting point.

More a comment than an answer here - fill out your profile, get rep :)

You should use port 587.
Also, you will need to have "Less Secure Apps" enabled, but make sure you understand the risks. This feature however is being deprecated in the near future, so you should consider an alternative:

Starting on September 30, 2024, less secure apps, third-party apps, or
devices that have you sign in with only your username and password
will no longer be supported for Google Workspace accounts. For exact
dates, visit Google Workspace Updates. To continue to use a specific
app with your Google Account, you’ll need to use a more secure type of
access that doesn’t share password data. Learn how to use Sign in with
Google.

You can read more about it here.
If you decide to continue down this road for now...
If Two-Factor Authentication is enabled, you will need to create an "App password". You can read how to do so here.
If you still have trouble connecting, consider using MailKit.
